# My lens won't settle on a focus point after dropping it — how bad is the damage?

Tags: lens, autofocus, equipment-damage

I have a Nikon 750. Like an idiot I let it fall with a Tamron 28-70 2.8 lens. Now on autofocus it oscillates backwards  and forwards through the focus point but never hits the focus point. I assume it is the lens since the body is fine with other lenses. It is ok with live view on the Tamron.

I assume it needs a repair. Any suggestions how bad or what the damage is?

Comment: 28-75mm or 24-70mm? I'm not familiar with a Tamron 28-70 f/2.8.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can come up with that would allow CDAF (live view) to function but not PDAF would be a badly de-centered element. If it's the 28-75 I think it would be cheaper to replace it with a used one.

Comment: Sorry, I miskeyed. It is a 24 - 70 with stabilization. Quite an expensive lens.

Comment: Only thing to do is send it in for an estimate... I don't expect repair will be cheap, but it might be the best option.